# Thermal API on Android devices always reports value of Zero

Tags: android, temperature

After testing the Thermal API with both a listener (PowerManager.OnThermalStatusChangedListener) and via direct polling (getCurrentThermalStatus()) I'm always getting a thermal reading of Zero, no matter how hot the device actually gets.
I tested on several devices running OS11 and OS12.

Anyone has any insight into why the thermal level is stuck at Zero?

*(I also that verified my code was indeed working by using an adb command to force the device to report thermal levels between 0 and 6 inclusive; this test worked fine and the device indeed reported the matching thermal level. However, the device in its **natural** state never reports anything above level Zero.)*

Comment: Are you sure your device has the hardware for this?  Not all do.  ANd obviously an emulator wouldn't.

Comment: @GabeSechan thnx. Yes I'm running on both a Pixel 6 (OS 12) and a MotoGFast(OS 11) and not on emulators